# Times series in R : how to change y-axis?

Tags: r, loops, time-series

New R user here, working with meteorological data (data frame is called "Stations"). Trying to plot 3 time series with temperature on y-axis with a regression line on each one, but I encounter a few problems and there is no error messages.

1. Loop doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why.
2. Didn't manage to change x-axis graduation values for years ("Année" in the data frame) instead of a number.
3. Title is the same for the 3 plots, how do I change it so each plot has its own title?
4. Regression line is not shown on the graph.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code :

````
for (i in c(6,8,10))
  plot(ts(Stations[,i]), col="dodgerblue4", xlab="Temps", ylab="Température", main="Genève")
for (i in c(6,8,10))
  abline(h=Stations[,i])```


Nb.enr   time   Année  Mois Jour T2m_GE pcp_GE T2m_PU pcp_PU T2m_NY
1      19810101  1981    1    1    1.3    0.3    2.8    0.0    2.3
2      19810102  1981    1    2    1.2    0.1    2.3    1.2    1.6
3      19810103  1981    1    3    4.1   21.8    4.9    5.2    3.8
4      19810104  1981    1    4    5.1   10.3    5.1   17.4    4.9
5      19810105  1981    1    5    0.9    0.0    1.0    0.1    0.8
6      19810106  1981    1    6    0.5    5.7    0.7    6.0    0.5
7      19810107  1981    1    7   -2.7    0.0   -2.1    0.1   -1.9
8      19810108  1981    1    8   -3.2    0.0   -4.1    0.0   -3.8
9      19810109  1981    1    9   -5.2    0.0   -3.5    0.0   -5.1
10     19810110  1981    1   10   -3.1   10.6   -0.9    6.0   -2.6
````

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! You are asking multiple different things, it's usually better to focus in one issue at a time to get better answers.

That being said, Can you elaborate on "doesn't seem to be working"? What is your expected output and what is the output you are currently getting? 

For 4, there's no regression shown in the code. What is making reference to?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the clarification, I'll keep that in mind for my next questions. I figured out loop is actually working, but datas are so close to each other that graphs look a lot alike. I also figured out how to change x-axis.

I still don't know how to change each graph's y-label and title independently. For 4, lm() is indeed lacking in the code. I added it, but I still don't know how to show y=mx+b equation on the graphs. Is there a function for it?